# Ler arquivo .js e escrever na página usando javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha Excel que quero exportar alguns dados para carregar em uma página HTML. Pesquisando na net descobri que isso só é possível se eu tiver esses dados em um arquivo .JS (tipo Dados.js).

Até aí tudo bem. Mas como ler os dados no arquivo .js e escrevê-los na minha página HTML, sem usar PHP, de preferência JavaScript? E tem outra coisa, sem ter de clicar em nada, tem que escrever automaticamente ao carregar a página.

Answer (score 1):

Sim é possivel ler um Excel usando JavaScript, desde que use a API File do JavaScript ou o .xls(x) esteja no mesmo servidor que a sua página, então usaria Ajax para pegar como string.

Depois de ler com File ou com Ajax pode usar esta lib: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Um exemplo de uso: http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-js/test/test.html, exemplo de uso:

- http://oss.sheetjs.com

Lendo um arquivo que esteja no mesmo servidor (host, porta e protocolo) com Ajax:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onload = function(e) {
  var data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
  var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type:"array"}); //Faz o "parse"
};
req.send();
```

Com File API:

```
//A variavel file se refere ao elemento <input type="file">

var rABS = typeof FileReader !== 'undefined' && FileReader.prototype && FileReader.prototype.readAsBinaryString;

var reader = new FileReader();
var name = file.name; //Nome do arquivo vindo do input

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var wb, arr;
    var readtype = {type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'base64' };
    if(!rABS) {
        arr = fixdata(data);
        data = btoa(arr);
    }
    function doit() {
        try {

            wb = XLSX.read(data, readtype); //Faz a leitura/parse

        } catch(e) { console.log(e); }
    }

    if(e.target.result.length > 1e6) opts.errors.large(e.target.result.length, function(e) { if(e) doit(); });
    else { doit(); }
};

if(rABS) reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
else reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode salvar seus dados em um arquivo `.js` no formato JSON, ler ele e exibir como quiser no evento `window.onload`. Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```js
var dados = {
  objeto1:{
    nome: 'teste',
    valor: 'batata'
  },
  objeto2:{
    nome: 'teste 2',
    valor: 'batata'
  }
}

window.onload = function () {
  for (var key in dados) {
    console.log(dados[key])    
  }
}
```

Comment: Artur, obrigado pela resposta. No entanto ainda tenho dúvidas:  A primeira parte do código é o "Dados.js"?  A segunda parte eu coloco no <Body> do HTML e ele já lê os dados?